# How to remove github history from a specific file?

Tags: git, github

I accidentally pushed a file with credentials. How do I remove all the history of that file? I cannot take down the repo because there is multiple people working on it.

Comment: If this repo is in any way public change your credentials immediately.

Comment: You're confusing git and github. (I can't edit the post because there'a already a pending edit)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it. If its public, its compromised. One thing you can do is create a new repo without sensitive data or remove that particular commit.